# Some doubts about RESTful web services?

Tags: web-services, rest, sample

I am new to the arena of RESTful services. I have been going through the articles about REST. And I have a lots of doubts. Please help me to clear these doubts. Thanks in advance.

1) For all RESTful web services, will there be a WSDL/WADL for describing the service? Is it mandatory to have service description? If there is no description, how can I know the data and its structure that I have to send along the HTTPRequest?

I read like, the request content could be any type (XML, JSON, YAML etc.). And there is no restriction for the content-type that could be send with request. Without a description how can I know the type of data that I am supposed to send?

2) By going through the articles, I have got the impression that RESTful services is used mainly for CRUD operation kind of services. Different HTTP verbs for different operations. But if you take web services, it can do all kinds of operations. For example, adding 2 numbers is not exactly a CRUD operation. If I use GET/POST to the resource which could do this operations for me, then will it be a violation of REST principles?

3) If you can point me to any public RESTful webservices that could be used for testing, I could try using the service and get an idea how complex the services could be.

Thanks in advance,
Paul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is normally no machine-readable service description. You would typically know what to send by reading the documentation for the service.

REST isn't limited to CRUD and the `PUT/GET/POST/DELETE` methods are **not** necessarily the same as *create/retrieve/update/delete*. REST-based services can do anything that SOAP-based web services can do. It is completely RESTful to send a GET request to a URI like `http://example.com/add?3,5`.

You can find a list of REST services at http://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory/1?protocol=REST.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I checked the REST services from the URL you provided. I found there are no service descriptions for any services there. So in the client side, we will not be able to use any code generation tools. It is upto the user, to create the request and invoke. This approach is ok, if the service is simple enough. But if the service is complex, wouldn't it be great to have a code generator?

Comment: Code generators aren't needed as much for REST services as they are with SOAP services, and although code generation has its own problems, yes it would still be nice to have that. Popular REST services, like the Facebook Graph API, do have libraries available.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your first question :

WSDL/WADL is not mandatory for restful webservices. Also, WSDL 1.1 HTTP binding was inadequate to describe restful webservice.

However, WSDL 2.0 can be used to describe it. Restful webservice should be used when the client and provider have mutual understanding of the contract.

Have a look at : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restwsdl/

Second : Yeah, you can accomplish almost everything from crud operations. Like stated in previous answer http://example.com/add?3,5. is a valid crud.

Answer (score 0):

1. No WSDL/WADL files. You get the HTTP protocol (e.g. GET, POST, UPDATE, DELETE) and everything else is up to you. Make sure to document your expected inputs and outputs accordingly.
2. No, RESTful web services are not restricted to CRUD. For your adding service, I would implement it as an "adder" resource which would take as input the 2 numbers to add. You could take these inputs as part of the url path (http://yourdomain.com/adder/1/2) or in the query string params (http://yourdomain.com/adder?var1=2&var2=2) or as inputs from an HTTP POST. Up to you.